# cannot remove fragment from activity

Tags: android

In **activity_layout.xml** main I add a fragment :

```
 <fragment
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.example.pack2.t9ahbin.FragA"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```

and in the Oncreate of Class **FragA** :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

in activity_layout.xml i add a button and set on click listener to it so when i click on it the fragment must be removed, but it didn't :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragA fragA ;
            fragA = (FragA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragA).commit();
        }
    });
```

when i click on it i got this error :

```
   >java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:653)
```

Comment: You can try this: [FragmentManager BackStackRecord.run throwing NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13395157/5124783)

Comment: You can try to add fragment in java code instead of in layout.

Comment: You can't remove `Fragment`s that are statically defined in your layout. As tiny sunlight suggests, you should add it dynamically in your Java code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I remove a fragment defined in a layout.xml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903874/can-i-remove-a-fragment-defined-in-a-layout-xml-file)

Comment: Ok, what is the best View Container to use to inflate a fragment in ?

Comment: I would say a `FrameLayout` is the norm.