# Android Fragment replacements from static to dynamic

Tags: android, fragment

I need to pass from a static Fragment in xmlembedded in Main activity to another one generated via code Java.
So the task is: 
1) Loading Main activity with Fragment_one embedded
2) Fragment one has a button in order to pass to fragment 2.

Activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentbookexample.FragmentOneLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one_layout"
    />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main_activity.java

```
package com.example.fragmentbookexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        b = findViewById (R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            FragmentTwoLayout second = new FragmentTwoLayout ();
            second.setArguments (getIntent ().getExtras ());

            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager ();
            FragmentTransaction trans = fm.beginTransaction ();
            trans.replace (R.id.fragment_one, second);
            trans.addToBackStack (null);
            trans.commit ();
        }
    });
    }

}
```

Fragment_one_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentOneLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Static Fragment XML"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="219dp"
        android:text="Pass to frag 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_two_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentTwoLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Dynamic Fragment JAVA"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Both Java code Fragments are created automatically with new->fragment->fragment(blank).

The question is why, when I replace frag1 with frag2, i see the button that is not contains in frag2 but in frag1?
I think replacement works well because the background color changes

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks it is not possible to remove a fragment that is created from an XML fragment tag, this answer seems to cover it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903874/can-i-remove-a-fragment-defined-in-a-layout-xml-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do any `FragmentTransaction` on a fragment container used with `<fragment>`.

If you are using [AndroidX Fragment `1.2.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0) or higher, you should use switch to using `FragmentContainerView` instead of the `<fragment>` tag, which **does** support using it alongside `FragmentTransaction`:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_one"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentbookexample.FragmentOneLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_one_layout"
/>
```